# run loop step on decimal on vba get stuck

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code to solve interest rate on vba, but the loop will run to the death!

Please help me to find what the problem is on the code!

Thank you very much!!!

```
Sub rate()

    Dim r As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim term0 As Long
    Dim term1 As Long
    Dim term2 As Long
    Dim term3 As Long
    Dim term4 As Long

    For r = 0.05 To 0.08 Step 0.001
        term0 = 10000
        term1 = 14000 / (1 + r)
        term2 = 18000 / (1 + r) ^ 2
        term3 = 22000 / (1 + r) ^ 3
        term4 = 25000 / (1 + r) ^ 4

        y = term0 + term1 + term2 + term3 + term4
        If y <= 75000 Then
            MsgBox (r)
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Thank you simoco and  Enigmativity!

After revision, here is the code which works great!

```
Sub rate()

    Dim r As Double
    Dim y As Long
    Dim term0, term1, term2, term3, term4 As Long

    r = 0.06
    Do
        r = r + 0.00001
        term0 = 10000
        term1 = 14000 / (1 + r)
        term2 = 18000 / (1 + r) ^ 2
        term3 = 22000 / (1 + r) ^ 3
        term4 = 25000 / (1 + r) ^ 4

        y = term0 + term1 + term2 + term3 + term4

    Loop Until y <= 75000

    Cells(11, 11) = r
    Cells(14, 12) = term0
    Cells(15, 12) = term1
    Cells(16, 12) = term2
    Cells(17, 12) = term3
    Cells(18, 12) = term4
    Cells(20, 12) = y

End Sub
```

Comment: You should make sure that you have `Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On` at the top of all of your VB.NET code. That will instruct the compiler to tell you when you are making errors like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Dim r As Long
```

to

```
Dim r As Double
```

Since you declared `r` as `Long` after type casting your loop would become:

```
For r = 0 To 0.08 Step 0.001
    'code
Next r
```

but when assigning `r = 0.05`, actual value of `r` would be `0` and `r=0+0.001` would give you `0` as well. And since `r` never increments, this produce infinity loop.

**BTW**, since you operating with double values, for correctness you should also change another values from `Long` type to `Double` as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Problem now is that there is no response on excel while running it after the change. The calculation itself should have a answer since I manually solve it.

Comment: what result do you expect? In first iteration (when `r=0.05`) your `y` is equal to `100400`. And since it's greater than `75000`, msgbox doesn't appear. For next iterations `y` is even more greater..

Comment: I would suggest using `Decimal` rather than `Double` for this loop. There is the slight chance that `Double` will introduce rounding errors that `Decimal` will not.

Comment: With value of r increasing, value of y is decreasing. I want to mgsbox to show the value of r when y is less or equal to 75000. :-)

Comment: @user3299007, I'm not sure:) Can you explain how increasing of r will decrease y?) Check your code again:) you have only `+` but never `-` values and increasing r would increse y as well

Comment: I got it! term2 = 18000 / (1 + r) ^ 2

Comment: Hi simoco, I have fixed that! I'm sorry to make you confused! This is my first time to ask question here, so I may click the wrong bottom! :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity, good point, but as follows from [this link](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/use-decimal-data-type-t3303795.html), in VBA (not VB.NET)  the `Decimal` data type can only be used within a `Variant`, that is, you cannot declare a variable to be of type
`Decimal`. You can, however, create a `Variant` whose subtype is `Decimal` using the `CDec` function. As for me, this is not convinient and causes performance issue:)

Comment: @simoco - Wow. I did not know that. That's bizarre. In that case I think I would change `r` to `Integer` and change the loop to be `For r = 0 to 80` and then do a cast and division inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Long vs Double has already been mentioned elsewhere.
Next thing is to add DoEvents somewhere in the loop. That makes it possible to break script execution and also makes Excel respond (a bit better).